# How can I create enums with constant values in Rust?

Tags: rust

I can do this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A(i32),
    B(i32),
}
```

but not this:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A(123), // 123 is a constant
    B(456), // 456 is a constant
}
```

I can create the structures for `A` and `B` with a single field and then implement that field, but I think there might be an easier way. Is there any?

Answer (score 170, accepted):

The best way to answer this is working out why you want constants in an enum: are you associating a value with each variant, or do you want each variant to *be* that value (like an `enum` in C or C++)?

For the first case, it probably makes more sense to just leave the enum variants with no data, and make a function:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A,
    B,
}

impl MyEnum {
    fn value(&self) -> i32 {
        match *self {
            MyEnum::A => 123,
            MyEnum::B => 456,
        }
    }
}
// call like some_myenum_value.value()
```

This approach can be applied many times, to associate many separate pieces of information with each variant, e.g. maybe you want a `.name() -> &'static str` method too. In the future, these functions can even be marked as `const` functions.

For the second case, you can assign explicit integer tag values, just like C/C++:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = 123,
    B = 456,
}
```

This can be `matched` on in all the same ways, but can also be cast to an integer `MyEnum::A as i32`. (Note that computations like `MyEnum::A | MyEnum::B` are not automatically legal in Rust: enums have specific values, they're not bit-flags.)

Comment: How do I match on the values (implemented in `value` function)?

Comment: @MatejKormuth this is late, but, you would just match on the return value of the method. Assuming your enum value is stored in a variable called `some_myenum_value`, just do `match some_myenum_value.value() { ...`.

Comment: As of Rust 1.46.0, one can use `pub const fn value(&self) -> i32` to avoid the overhead of evaluating the `match` statement at runtime.

Comment: `pub const fn` will allow the function to be called in a `const` context, but it is unlikely to impact behaviour otherwise. 

Specifically `const X: int = MyEnum::A.value()` isn't allowed with just `fn value`, but _is_ allowed with `const fn value`. When called outside a const context, the `const` doesn't do anything (e.g. the optimiser will inline and evaluate the `match`, if it can, with or without the `const` annotation).

Comment: Will the first case be optimised by the compiler?

Answer (score 48):

Creating an "enum" with constant values, can be augmented using structs and [associated constants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/associated-constants.html).
This is similar to how crates like [bitflags](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags) works and what it would generate.

Additionally, to prevent direct instantiation of `MyEnum` you can tag it with [`#[non_exhaustive]`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes/type_system.html).

```rust
#[non_exhaustive]
struct MyEnum;

impl MyEnum {
    pub const A: i32 = 123;
    pub const B: i32 = 456;
}
```

Then you simply use the "enum" as you otherwise would, by accessing `MyEnum::A` and `MyEnum::B`.

---

Additionally, if we want to be able to iterate all variants, then we need to manually add a constant containing all variants. We could add something like this:

```rust
impl MyEnum {
    pub const VARIANTS: &'static [i32] = &[Self::A, Self::B];
}

for variant in MyEnum::VARIANTS {
    println!("{:?}", variant);
}
```

Which will output `123` then `456`.

---

Using [`macro_rules!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html) we can remove a lot of the boilerplate, and turn it into a simple macro:

```rust
macro_rules! def_enum {
    ($vis:vis $name:ident => $ty:ty {
        $($variant:ident => $val:expr),+
        $(,)?
    }) => {
        #[non_exhaustive]
        $vis struct $name;

        impl $name {
            $(
                pub const $variant: $ty = $val;
            )+

            pub const VARIANTS: &'static [$ty] = &[$(Self::$variant),+];
        }
    };
}
```

Now we can just do the following to define the `enum`:

```rust
def_enum!(pub MyEnum => i32 {
    A => 123,
    B => 456,
});
```

Everything still remains the same. We're still able to access `MyEnum::A`, `MyEnum::B`, and `MyEnum::VARIANTS`.

---

Additionally, since the macro uses a `expr` and not a `literal` for `$val`. That also means that values can be [constant expressions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/const_eval.html). In other words, the following is also completely valid:

```rust
const fn add(a: i32, b: i32) -> i32 {
    a + b
}

def_enum!(pub MyEnum => i32 {
    A => add(2, 3),
    B => {
        let (a, b) = (1, 2);
        let c = (a + b) * 3;
        c
    },
});

assert_eq!(MyEnum::A, 5);
assert_eq!(MyEnum::B, 9);

assert_eq!(MyEnum::VARIANTS, &[5, 9]);
```

---

If we don't want `i32` to be the exposed type of our variants, but instead want it to be `MyEnum`, then we can wrap all `i32`s in `MyEnum` instead. We can achieve that by changing our macro into the following:

```rust
macro_rules! def_enum {
    (
        $(#[$attr:meta])*
        $vis:vis $name:ident => $ty:ty {
            $($variant:ident => $val:expr),+
            $(,)?
        }
    ) => {
        $(#[$attr])*
        $vis struct $name($ty);

        impl $name {
            $(
                pub const $variant: Self = Self($val);
            )+

            pub const VARIANTS: &'static [Self] = &[$(Self::$variant),+];

            pub const fn get(self) -> $ty {
                self.0
            }
        }
    };
}
```

If we don't care about someone doing `MyEnum(12345)`, then we could just make the tuple field `pub`. Otherwise, we'd need a `get()` method (which the above includes.)

Additionally, the addition of `$attr:meta` allows us to add `#[derive(...)]` and any other attributes.

```rust
def_enum!(
    #[derive(PartialEq,Eq, Debug)]
    pub MyEnum => i32 {
        A => 123,
        B => 456,
    }
);

assert_eq!(MyEnum::A.get(), 5);
assert_eq!(MyEnum::B.get(), 9);

assert_eq!(MyEnum::VARIANTS, &[MyEnum::A, MyEnum::B]);
```

Comment: Can you iterate over every variant here ?

Comment: @gruvw Quite a bit later, but I've updated the answer

Answer (score 6):

People looking at this may stumble upon the introduction and deprecation of `FromPrimitive`. A possible replacement which might also be useful here is [enum_primitive](https://andersk.github.io/enum_primitive-rs/enum_primitive/). It allows you to use C-like enums and have them cast between numeric and logical representation:

```
#[macro_use]
extern crate enum_primitive;
extern crate num;

use num::FromPrimitive;

enum_from_primitive! {
    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    enum FooBar {
        Foo = 17,
        Bar = 42,
        Baz,
    }
}

fn main() {
    assert_eq!(FooBar::from_i32(17), Some(FooBar::Foo));
    assert_eq!(FooBar::from_i32(42), Some(FooBar::Bar));
    assert_eq!(FooBar::from_i32(43), Some(FooBar::Baz));
    assert_eq!(FooBar::from_i32(91), None);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = 123,
    B = 456,
}

assert_eq!(MyEnum::A as i32, 123i32);
assert_eq!(MyEnum::B as i32, 456i32);
```

Comment: While this solution appealed the most to me because of its simplicity, I couldn't get it to work while testing a variable using `match`. The MyEnum::A values can not be cast to i32 in a match arm.

Answer (score 3):

The [enum-map](https://crates.io/crates/enum-map) crate provides the ability to assign a value to the enum record. What is more, you can use this macro with different value types.

```
use enum_map::{enum_map, Enum}; // 0.6.2

#[derive(Debug, Enum)]
enum Example {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

fn main() {
    let mut map = enum_map! {
        Example::A => 1,
        Example::B => 2,
        Example::C => 3,
    };
    map[Example::C] = 4;

    assert_eq!(map[Example::A], 1);

    for (key, &value) in &map {
        println!("{:?} has {} as value.", key, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to give another idea.

```rust
#[allow(non_snake_case, non_upper_case_globals)]
mod MyEnum {
    pub const A: i32 = 123;
    pub const B: i32 = 456;
}
```

Then you can simply use it by accessing `MyEnum::A` and `MyEnum::B` or `use MyEnum::*`.

The advantage of doing this over [associated constants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/associated-constants.html) is that you can even nest more enums.

```rust
#[allow(non_snake_case, non_upper_case_globals)]
mod MyEnum {
    pub const A: i32 = 123;
    pub const B: i32 = 456;

    #[allow(non_snake_case, non_upper_case_globals)]
    mod SubEnum {
        pub const C: i32 = 789;
    }
}
```

For my project I wrote a macro that automatically generates indexes and sets initial values.

```rust
#[macro_export]
macro_rules! cnum {
    (@step $_idx:expr,) => {};
    (@step $idx:expr, $head:ident, $($tail:ident,)*) => {
        pub const $head: usize = $idx;
        cnum!(@step $idx + 1usize, $($tail,)*);
    };
    ($name:ident; $($n:ident),* $(,)* $({ $($i:item)* })?) => {
        cnum!($name; 0usize; $($n),* $({ $($i)* })?);
    };
    ($name:ident; $start:expr; $($n:ident),* $(,)* $({ $($i:item)* })?) => {
        #[macro_use]
        #[allow(dead_code, non_snake_case, non_upper_case_globals)]
        pub mod $name {
            use crate::cnum;
            $($($i)*)?
            cnum!(@step $start, $($n,)*);
        }
    };
}
```

Then you can use it like this,

```rust
cnum! { Tokens;
    EOF,
    WhiteSpace,
    Identifier,
    {
        cnum! { Literal; 100;
            Numeric,
            String,
            True,
            False,
            Nil,
        }

        cnum! { Keyword; 200;
            For,
            If,
            Return,
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a crate [enumeration](https://crates.io/crates/enumeration) just for this.

Example using my crate:

```rust
use enumeration::prelude::*;

enumerate!(MyEnum(u8; i32)
    A = 123
    B = 456
);

pub fn main() {
    assert_eq!(*MyEnum::A.value(), 123);
    assert_eq!(*MyEnum::B.value(), 456);
}
```