# Is it possible to assign char values to enum variants?

Tags: rust, char, enumeration

In C++, I can define an enum class where constant `char` values are given to different fields:

```cpp
enum class BasicOperators : char {
    plus='+',
    minus='-',
    mul='*',
    div='/'
}
```

From [Enums with constant values in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928569/enums-with-constant-values-in-rust), I am aware that I can define an enum with an integer:

```
enum MyEnum {
    A = 123,
    b = 456,
}
```

If I define an enum with `char` values like this:

```
enum BasicOperators {
    Plus = '+',
    Minus = '-',
    Mul = '*',
    Div = '/',
}
```

the compiler complains:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/lib.rs:2:12
  |
2 |     Plus = '+',
  |            ^^^ expected isize, found char
```

Comment: Note that the closest approximation of the `char` type in C++ is the `u8` type in Rust. (The types are not completely equivalent, because in C++ it is not defined whether `char` is signed, nor does it always have 8 bits, but it's close enough in this context.) The closest equivalent of the Rust type `char` in C++ is `char32_t`.