# Can enum variants have constant associated values?

Tags: enums, rust, constants

I have the code ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7abd452c77afe7d95f0b7a2cc52f6f85)):

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

// We have some arbitrary struct (given values just placeholders)
struct SomeStruct {
    x: f32,
    y: usize,
}

fn main() {
    // We have some hashmap which contains the names (keys) and properties (values) of items.
    //  These are known at compile time.
    let hashmap: HashMap<&str, SomeStruct> = vec![
        ("a", SomeStruct { x: 2., y: 2 }),
        ("b", SomeStruct { x: 3.5, y: 1 }),
        ("c", SomeStruct { x: 0., y: 5 }),
    ]
    .into_iter()
    .collect();

    // We then have a bunch of data which arbitrarily references the names of these items.
    //  This data is also known at compile time.
}
```

Constantly typing `"a"`,`"b"`, etc when needing to refer to the items is bad.

An enum could possibly be used to make this better, something like:

```
enum Items {
    A = SomeStruct { x: 2., y: 2 },
    B = SomeStruct { x: 3.5, y: 1 },
    C = SomeStruct { x: 0., y: 5 },
}
```

This would effectively be a `const` enum, such that when referring to these items in the future we could simply do `Items::A` or `&Items::A` rather than `'a'` and having to do the necessary hashing.

It seems that doing this is not viable.

Is there a way to use a `const enum`? Or is there an alternative better solution?

While this question may be a duplicate of [How can I create enums with constant values in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928569/how-can-i-create-enums-with-constant-values-in-rust) the solutions proposed under that question did not work when using an arbitrary struct. The [solution vallentin added](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759540/155423) does but this solution really applies more to this circumstance where the other solutions do not work. I think it provides a better clearer answer in context of this question where the other simpler solutions do not work.

Comment: The [accepted answer is "match in a function"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36928678/155423), which is in this accepted answer, the [enum_map solution works for your case](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3258a9e55b99e7fbf4ad43815778cbe2), and the associated const answer — 3 of the 4 answers apply to your case, only the answers specific to primitives don't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [associated constants](https://doc.rust-lang.org/edition-guide/rust-2018/trait-system/associated-constants.html),
which is similar to how the [bitflags](https://crates.io/crates/bitflags) crate works. If you add `#[non_exhaustive]` to `Items`, you can prevent instantiation of `Items`.

```rust
#[non_exhaustive]
struct Items;

impl Items {
    pub const A: SomeStruct = SomeStruct { x: 2., y: 2 };
    pub const B: SomeStruct = SomeStruct { x: 3.5, y: 1 };
    pub const C: SomeStruct = SomeStruct { x: 0., y: 5 };
}
```

---

Alternatively, if you're using Nightly, you could have a match in a const method, using `const_if_match`. Which was also [lately stabilized](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/72437).

```rust
#![feature(const_if_match)]

enum Items {
    A,
    B,
    C,
}

impl Items {
    const fn value(self) -> SomeStruct {
        use Items::*;
        match self {
            A => SomeStruct { x: 2.0, y: 2 },
            B => SomeStruct { x: 3.5, y: 1 },
            C => SomeStruct { x: 0., y: 5 },
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I encourage you to move your answer to the duplicate question, as it would be a unique solution among the other answers.

Comment: `#![feature(const_if_match)]` has been stabilized so the attribute isn't necessary on nightly anymore. It'll reach the next beta, and next-next stable.