# Assign associated non mutable constant data to enum variants

Tags: rust, enums, serde, associated-value

Note:
My question is similar to this question, but doesn't seem to solve my use case.
[Can enum variants have constant associated values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759099/can-enum-variants-have-constant-associated-values)

**Problem explanation**

My server returns a country (very long list) which internally is mapped to an enum (there is a closed set of valid possibilities known ahead of time).

I need to have some data associated to the country (for instance the language).

The associated data is "constant" and for ergonomic/performance reasons it makes sense for the data to be "attached" to the enum variation.

Contrived example:

I have a list of languages and a list of countries

```
#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize)
enum Language {
  English,
  Spanish,
  French,
// .. 100 more
}

#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize)
enum Country {
  USA,
  England,
  France,
  Mexico,
  Spain
// .. 100 more
}
```

**Internally** I would like the enum to associate the language value to the country implicitly:

```
// what I want

#[derive(Serialize,Deserialize)
enum Country {
  USA(Language),
  England(Language),
  // ... more countries with associated languages...
}
```

1. When creating a "Country", I don't want  to supply the language, rather just `Country::country_name` (without the language)
2. when serializing/deserializing, the language should be implicitly added

Looking at serde.rs documentation you could add a field attribute

```
#[serde(default)]
```

or

```
#[serde(default = "path")]
```

but

1. `default` there isn't a default language for all countries - rather it depends on the country variant it is contained in
2. `path` - the function is called without the country value, so similar effect to `default`

Some options I considered

1. implement serialize/deserialize by hand - but i have many cases and error prone
2. lazy constant values ? verbose

Comment: I'd dare say there is a neat solution with macros that automate that "by hand" part, but I don't know Serde enough to show the code.

Comment: I know you said, that you wante to attach the `Language` to the `Country` variant, but there's no need to. You can create a tuple struct: `struct Localization(Country, Language)` and then have the country deserialized like you normally would and maybe have a `Localization` "constructor" that takes the `Country` and automatically searches for the correct `Language`. Is that an approach worth to dig in?

Comment: Why not use `std::collections::HashMap<Country, Language>`?

Answer (score 0):

Not an ideal solution but reasonable in my use case:

use `lazy_static` or `const` data (in my situation the data wasn't const'able per the example in the question)

```
impl Country {
  fn language() -> '&static Language { // my language is more complex than just a simple type described in this question so i do want to have static instances . understandably in the answer it seems overkill
     match self {
        USA => {
          lazy_static! {
             let lang: Language = Language::English; /// in reality more data here...
          }
          &lang
        }
        France => { ...}
        // ... more countries
     }
  }
}
```