# Java enum-like behavior in Rust

Tags: rust, enums

I want to have an enum where each value in the enum stores a constant array of bytes that represent the RGBA values for a color. In Java I would do this:

```java
public enum Color {
    BLACK([0x0C, 0x00, 0x05, 0xFF]),
    BLUE([0x00, 0x2D, 0xFF, 0xFF]),
    RED([0xFF, 0x3E, 0x00, 0xFF]);

    private final byte[] rgba;

    Color(byte[] rgba) {
      this.rgba = rgba;
    }

    public int[] value() {
      return rgba;
    }
}
```

Then I could pass around Color types and just use color.value() to get the bytes out. This is what I have in Rust:

```
struct Color;

impl Color {
    pub const BLACK: [u8; 4] = [0x0C, 0x00, 0x05, 0xFF];
    pub const BLUE: [u8; 4] = [0x00, 0x2D, 0xFF, 0xFF];
    pub const RED: [u8; 4] = [0xFF, 0x3E, 0x00, 0xFF];
}
```

But this means that anywhere I want to pass a Color the type is `[u8; 4]`. I could call the struct `Colors` and then do `pub type Color = [u8; 4]`. Then you could have the type as `Color` but then it would be `Colors::BLACK` which seems weird.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I create enums with constant values in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36928569/how-can-i-create-enums-with-constant-values-in-rust)

Comment: ^ if `Color` can only be black, blue, or red then that's the way to do, but if it can have any r, g, b, a value, then it should probably be `struct Color([u8; 4]);` with your constants defined like `pub const BLACK: Color = Color([...]);`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to have a strong type for the byte array in the `Color` struct, you can use the following notation, called a [tuple struct](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.9.0/book/structs.html#tuple-structs):

```
struct Color([u8; 4]);

impl Color {
    pub const BLACK: Color = Color([0x0C, 0x00, 0x05, 0xFF]);
    pub const BLUE: Color = Color([0x00, 0x2D, 0xFF, 0xFF]);
    pub const RED: Color = Color([0xFF, 0x3E, 0x00, 0xFF]);
}

fn main() {
    // classic way of accessing data
    println!("{:?}", Color::BLACK.0);
    
    // using destructuring
    let Color(bytes) = Color::BLUE;
    println!("{:?}", bytes);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fbd49f4813b9bd23018ef39130130eb0)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a crate [enumeration](https://crates.io/crates/enumeration) just for this.

Example using my crate:

```rust
use enumeration::prelude::*;

enumerate!(pub Color(u8; [u8; 4])
    Black = [0x0C, 0x00, 0x05, 0xFF]
    Blue = [0x00, 0x2D, 0xFF, 0xFF]
    Red = [0xFF, 0x3E, 0x00, 0xFF]
);

pub fn main() {
    assert_eq!(*Color::Black.value(), [0x0C, 0x00, 0x05, 0xFF]);
    assert_eq!(*Color::Blue.value(), [0x00, 0x2D, 0xFF, 0xFF]);
    assert_eq!(*Color::Red.value(), [0xFF, 0x3E, 0x00, 0xFF]);
}
```

Comment: I think using a library is overkill for this. I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36928678/2037998) fixes the problem in a much simpler way.

Comment: @RalphBisschops actually my macro does just that, it just produces enum with method that uses `match` and I tried my best to make it small (no dependency and only a macro)