# Const enums where each variant is an unwrap of `Result` in Rust

Tags: rust, enums, constants

I have read:

[Can enum variants have constant associated values? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62759540/19504610)

[How can I create enums with constant values in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36928678/19504610)

My question takes these questions one step further by considering if we can have each enum variant is an 'unwrap' of `Result`, returning the `Ok` variant.

```rust
use std::str::FromStr;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq, Hash)]
struct Address(String);

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
enum Error {
    ParsePointError
}

impl FromStr for Address { // conversion from `&str` to `Address` returns a `Result`
    type Err = Error;

    fn from_str(s: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Err> {
        if s.len() >= 20usize {
            return Err(Error::ParsePointError)
        }
        Ok(Address(s.to_string()))
    }
}

struct TokenAddress {}

impl TokenAddress {
    pub const HERO: Address = Address::from_str("0x1234567").expect("ERROR: Unable to parse `HERO`");
}
```

The main API I wish to achieve is to be able to use `TokenAddress::HERO` and this should return me a value of type `Address`.

`lazy_static!(...)` may help in this case where each value defined within the macro is initialized only once, however, it would be a hassle to define individual variable name within the macro itself, e.g.

```
lazy_static!{
    pub static ref HERO_TOKEN_ADDRESS: Address = "...".expect("...");
}
```

I wish to use it in my `main()` like so:

```
fn main() {
    let hero_token_address = TokenAddress::HERO;
    println!("{:?}", hero_token_address);
}
```

[Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c8babe646cebcd851071f70ee36ab3f1)

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with enums except for the `Namespace::Value` syntax which you can simply get with modules.

Comment: I don't understand why you think `lazy_static` is a hassle.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman Not that it is a true hassle, but more like I want to have the syntax of something like `TokenAddress::HERO` to be a value of type `Address`.

Comment: It's almost: `TokenAddress::HERO.clone()`.